# java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument(s) in call: getBytes()

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, odbc

I was trying to convert a blob to string with the following code:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

Blob newValueBLOB = rs.getBlob("NEW_VALUE");
System.out.println(newValueBLOB);
String newValue = new String(newValueBLOB.getBytes(0, (int) newValueBLOB.length()));
```

My database is Oracle and the connection is established properly.  I've found a similar answer but mine is not working!

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Javadoc for [Blob#getBytes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html#getBytes(long,%20int)):

> byte[] getBytes(long pos, int length) throws SQLException
> pos - the ordinal position of the first byte in the BLOB value to be extracted; the first byte is at position 1

So, your call to `getBytes()` should be passing in 1 as the start position, not zero:

```
String newValue = new String(newValueBLOB.getBytes(1, (int) newValueBLOB.length()));
```

As an alternative, possibly simpler, you could just use `ResultSet#getBytes` directly:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
byte[] newValue = rs.getBytes("NEW_VALUE");
String newValueStr = new String(newValue);
```